# how to rosmake as sudo?

Tags: openni, rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi guys! I installed openni on a "old" laptop that doesn't support SSE3 instructions. So I did [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/341/how-to-compile-openni_ros-with-sse2-only-support) modification on the CMakeLists.txt but I don't know how to rosmake it to generate the new node. I tried to rename ROS_NOBUILD but when I do rosmake I got this message:

```
mkdir: impossible create directory "build": Permission denied
```

thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10661/how-to-rosmake-as-sudo?/) by [Bemfica](https://answers.ros.org/users/540/bemfica/) on ROS Answers with karma: 482 on 2011-07-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I assume you installed from .debs. Changing files inside the .debs installed directories is not recommended (as any update at a later date could mess up your install). You should install from source following the directions for your OS and chosen ROS release.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bemfica](https://answers.ros.org/users/540/bemfica/) on 2011-07-20**:
It works Eric. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd suggest that you generally don't modify and recompile the stock installation but if you want to, then you need to:

```
sudo bash
. /opt/ros/diamondback/setup.bash   // assuming you have diamondback installed
roscd {desired package}
rm ROS_NOBUILD         // in each package that you want to recompile
rosmake
```

---

Originally posted by [ben](https://answers.ros.org/users/33/ben/) with karma: 674 on 2011-07-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bemfica](https://answers.ros.org/users/540/bemfica/) on 2011-07-20**:
by safety I'm trying the Eric suggestion first! but thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you can switch to root account and run rosmake like "`sudo rosmake`"  by

`sudo -s`    <- change to root

and

`rosmake`    <-- work like `sudo rosmake`

---

Originally posted by [embeddedheaven](https://answers.ros.org/users/169/embeddedheaven/) with karma: 121 on 2011-07-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2